# Keychain have twice Distribution certificate added

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate, distribution, keychain

When I build an app it shows me this error:

[image]

When I deleted the previous one certificate, everything starts working fine. So my question is if deleted it once how it again added in the keychain? and why it is added again instead of one certificate being there in the keychain?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting an error message about having an extra distribution certificate - because you have an extra distribution certificate!

My guess is that you are getting it pulled back down to your machine from the Provisioning Portal by Xcode.

Have you recently revoked a distribution certificate and then tried to delete from KeychainAccess? If so, did you delete the public and private keys associated with it?

Go into KeychainAccess and check if you have any orphan private keys, if you have any which could be linked to an old distribution certificate then delete them (deleting a developer or distribution certificate without deleting its public and private key is not deleting it properly - you need to delete both keys AND the certificate)

then go back to Xcode and in the Organiser screen hit the 'refresh' button - then check KeychainAccess again - with any luck Xcode will not have downloaded the naughty certificate and your problem has been solved. However if you now have your rogue certificate back then it may be that the provisioning profile you have been using needs to be changed...

BTW, make sure you look in the 'system' and 'system roots' keychains as well as the 'login' keychain.